# Common Travel Area Spouse

Tags: united-kingdom

I am an Irish citizen and I know that under the Common Travel Area I will be able to live/work in the UK, even post-Brexit. What I am wondering is if my spouse will be able to join me easily? He has dual American/Australian citizenship.

I have seen this question asked of a British person going to Ireland, but not the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: I think this https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit may help

Comment: There is some info about that (not very useful or reassuring) at the end of this [guidance webpage](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-guidance/common-travel-area-guidance).

Answer (score 1):

If you move to the UK before the end of the transition period (which is now planned to coincide with the end of this year), you and your spouse will be able to register for the [EU settlement scheme](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families).  It is free of charge and relatively quick and easy, and citizens of Australia and of the US (among other countries) do not need to apply for a family permit before moving to the UK.

If you move after the end of the transition period, then your spouse will have to apply for a [spouse visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse).  The path from spouse visa to ILR costs several thousand pounds over a few years.  It is not nearly as straightforward as the settlement scheme.  Among other burdens, you must show that you meet the [financial requirements](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/proof-income).